# File transfer

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an IIS located on serverA

I have userA at locationA who has opened a content management system site, hosted on serverA.

One of the features of the system is that it allows the user to move a file to LocationB, all within the same network. Now when this move occurs and due to bandwidth restrictions, would this file move from LocationA to serverA to LocationB or is there a way for me to move the file from LocationA to LocationB without going through serverA, i.e using local memory on serverA

I am not using BITS at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on Ian's suggestion of posting direct to server2, you're going to need some sort of webserver (prob IIS, but you could custom write one, that just accepts the CMS form submission and puts files where they need to go)

Answer (score 0):

That's entirely going to depend on how the CMS works - if it does an `scp` in the background, then the answer is yes - it skips the local machine.

If it uses http to transfer it to the user's machine then back out, the answer is "no".

Answer (score 0):

Is userA uploading the file from their machine? If so you might be able to do this by setting the action attribute on the form:

```
<form method="post" action="http://serverB/locationB" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...
    <input type="file" ... />
    ...
</form>
```